# Associating an Object correctly with a specific Date(SQL & Rails 4)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an employee schedule of sorts. Before I state my problem, I will give some context.

First of all, I have some Employees for a Club. I have them connected with the Users model for a validation reason.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :clubs, through: :employees
 end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club
end

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :users, through: :employees
end
```

I plan on making another model called `Shifts`. Employees would be able to have many shifts. These Shifts have to be associated with a Club and Employee.

The Shift table must have the following elements:

```
:name_of_employee(pulled from Users table)
:date_of_shift(date)
:start_of_shift(time)
:end_of_shift(time)
```

Now the problem is that for my app, I will generate 7 dated divs on the page like so:

```
|March 1, 2016|                                                         |

|March 2, 2016|                                                         |

|March 3, 2016|                                                         |

|March 4, 2016|                                                         |

|March 5, 2016|                                                         |

|March 6, 2016|                                                         |

|March 7, 2016|                                                         |
```

The dates for these divs will change depending on the current date. My question is: **How do I associate the Shift model correctly with Clubs and Employees and also render Shifts in the correct div based on `:date_of_shift`?**

For example, all of the shifts that have `date_of_shift: March 1, 2016` must be rendered in the appropriate div. Do I have to create a Date Model or are there helpers to make this easier?

Comment: A separate comment on the User - Employee relationship. I don't know the context but would it makes more sense to me that a User would have many Employments (rather than a user having many Employees). Your life would be simplified significantly by removing the `User` model unless it is 100% necessary I feel!

Comment: Also as a shift will belong to an employee, you will have an employee_id in each row of the shifts table - allowing you to call `shift.employee.name` or something similar. This is preferable to :name_of_employee(pulled from Users table) being included in the shifts table.

Comment: I like your idea of calling it Employments. Will definitely change it to that.  The User model is necessary for many other features on the app so I cannot get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the simplest solution is to define some helper methods to deal with conditionality of whether you render certain instances of `shift` or not. Yes there is some repetition (in this example) but it's easy to understand I would argue.

```
def day_one?
 true if shift.date == Date.today
end

def day_two?
 true if shift.date == Date.today + 1
end
```

You can then use these helper methods in your views when referring to shifts as required.

Comment: Oh perfect! Makes sense. Also, another question.I will render these shifts on a "Club Page". Since employee has `:user_id` and `:club_id` as foreign keys, I can just filter the shifts by matching the `:club_id` with the specific Club right? Therefore I wouldn't need model association between Shifts and Clubs, correct?

Comment: I don't know your domain but it sounds like a `shift` `belongs_to` both an `employee` and also a `club` and this association is something to have. Thus enabling you to call `club.shifts` or `club.shifts.where(employee_id: @user.id)` or something like this. Presuming you have set `@user` to `current_user` or any other user you wanted.